# How to prove the induced map; $g_* : C(Y) \rightarrow C(X)$, induced from the map $g \in C(X, Y)$, endowed with fine topology is an embedding.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, function-spaces

Considering $X$ as a tychonoff space and $Y$ any metric space, and taking the fine topology on function space $C(Y, \Bbb R)=C(Y)$ and $C(X, \Bbb R)=C(X)$. Then the continuous map $g \in C(X, Y)$ induces a function $g_* : C(Y) \rightarrow C(X)$, as $g_*(f) = \phi(f, g) = g \circ f, f \in C(Y)$.

How to prove the induced map; $g_* : C(Y) \rightarrow C(X)$, induced from the map $g \in C(X, Y)$, endowed with fine topology is an embedding.
Taking $g$ as continuous, onto and open map. How to prove that $g_*$ is an embedding.

I can prove it continuous and bijection but i don't know how to prove it open map. Can anybody help?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Taking $g$ as continuous, onto and open map, how to prove that $g_* $ is an embedding?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I have saved the edits. Could yopu please answer?

Comment: The topology on $C(X,Y)$ is of course irrelevant. Injectivity of $g_\ast$ is because we can separate points of $X$ by real-valued continuous functions. Why do you want $Y$ to be metrisable?

Comment: Injectivity already follows from $g$ being onto of course. Still, why does $Y$ have to be metrisable?

Comment: To prove it onto i think we need to take $Y$ as metric space.

Comment: Why? $g_\ast$ will usually not be onto $C(X)$, but onto some subspace of it.

Comment: Note that my proof of continuity of $g_\ast$ holds if the "radius functions" are not required to be continuous themselves. I just noticed this. Do you demand it?  I saw McCoy does only use continuous $\epsilon: X \to (0,+\infty)$.. So I'd even double check whether $g_\ast$ is even continuous..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma True. The radius function needs to be continuous. Then how can we prove it is continuous.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma But i think in that proof we are taking a basis element from the ring $C(X, R)$ and the radius function is also taken by us. I think there is no need to check if continuous or not, basic open set will definitely contain a continuous radius function with respect to the topology defined on the space.

Comment: I don’t think that’s clear at all.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Then what is the other way pne can prove  that map continuous? Did you crosscheck it?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma If we take $g$ to b a retraction from $Y$ to a subspace of it say $Z$, and $g$ is onto. Then i think we can prove $g_*$ to be onto and finally an embedding. Could you help me write the proof?